# I cannot connect to a website cuz of a SSL cert error (python)

Tags: python, ssl, connection, runtime-error, client

```
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorCertificateError: Cannot connect to host siren.pp.ua:443 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, "[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: IP address mismatch, certificate is not valid for '207.154.193.88'. (_ssl.c:1002)")]

i want to use uasiren API for monitoring alerts in Terminal
```

I have tried to install older ver of pip but seems like it does not help at all

Comment: Looks like https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/5110 which was fixed nearly 3 years ago. Maybe you are running an old version of Python and aiohttp. Too few details in your question to be sure though.

Answer (score 0):

I hade the similar issue with python.
Likely you need to install certificates from the python package. 
Go to the `Python` folder and click `Install Certificates.command`
Should help.

Comment: This is unlikely to help. It has nothing to do with missing root CA. The problem is instead that the certificate validation is done with the IP address instead of the hostname of the server and thus does not match the subject/SAN of the certificate.